# Is it possible in groovy, c++ style macro

Tags: groovy

I want to type less characters for the word 'static' in my groovy script. Is it possible to have some macro that substitutes 'st' for 'static' in my script.

Comment: Nearly every IDE supports code snippets that can replace that. (And using a C++ macro like that would be extremely bad practice)

Comment: There isn't very much meaning in a language only you can understand.

Comment: I hope you are asking this just for a code golf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groovy doesn't have C-style string substitution macros like this. [Groovy's macros](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.5.0-rc-3/html/documentation/#_macros) are about performing metaprogramming transformations on the abstract syntax tree, rather than "just" doing string substitutions.